# Cap keyword does not work

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture chapter numbers in a set of strings.

Usually the chapter numbers begin with a number and end with a dot or contain the term 'chapter'.

This is the regex I framed `(?:^(\d)\. |Chapter (.+?)\s)`. The data is [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5E(%5Cd)%5C.%20%7CChapter%20(.%2B%3F)%5Cs)&test_string=Chapter%20One%20-%20Negotiate%20in%20Three%20Dimensions%0A1.%20The%203-D%20Negotiation%20Alternative%0AChapter%20Two%20-%20Do%20a%203-D%20Audit%20of%20Barriers%20to%20Agreement%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

I am unable to catch the number that begins at the start of the string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use a multiline modifier, otherwise `^` is only considered for the start of the string, not the start of each line.

Comment: At the start of a string or line?